# How to show Not Found Page (404) when accessing AJAX pages

Tags: php

I am able to prevent from direct access from browser address bar to the AJAX page (I exist the PHP code if they access from the browser). For instance this an AJAX page: [www.example.com/ajax/ajax.php](http://www.example.com/ajax/ajax.php) and I need to show to users that this page doesn't exist - similar to what happens when they access the pages that really don't exist. I perform that from sites-available like below:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /page_not_found.php
```

So, when users access the page: [www.example.com/ajax/ajax.php](http://www.example.com/ajax/ajax.php), I need them to see the content of the page: page_not_found.php

NOTE 1: AJAX Page is the page which has PHP code that is reached from Javascript and the users must not access those pages as they don't have visible code to be shown into HTML.

NOTE 2: At the top of the AJAX page, I check the source of access, if it is from the browser address bar, then I exit the code, I use $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'].

How I do protect my ajax pages from direct access from browser:

To make the code simple, on the top of the page, I add:

```
// To prevent from accessing the ajax page from the browser address bar direct
if( strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) != 'http://example.com/index.php'){
    exit; // I need to show the content of the 404 error page before this exit 
}
```

I don't want to do any redirection! Looking for a fake way to show that page not found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the problem by using **file_get_contents** to read the **not_found.php** page before exiting the code. So, this way, it will be shown as any real page doesn't exist on the server and also the no redirection will occur.

```
// To prevent from accessing the ajax page from the browser address bar directly
if( strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) != 'http://example.com/index.php'){

    header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");        

    file_get_contents("http://example.com/not_found.php"); // will bring the 404 page 

    exit; // no more execution
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Was not sure what do you mean by `AJAX` page, but let's assume you are using some `javascript` to grab contents of the page. Whenever you sending request to the page, that doesn't exist, you should probably check for `404 header` in your response and redirect/display your `page_no_found.php`.

For example:

```
xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', 'non_existen_ajax_page', true);
xhr.send();
if(xhr.status == 404) {
  //redirect or display to user your page_not_found.php
} else {
  //display content of a page
}
```

Comment: AJAX Page is the page which has PHP code that is reached from Javascript and the users must not access those pages as they don't have visible code to be shown into HTML.

I need to show the content of 404 page when users access that page from the browser and I don't need to do any redirection.

Answer (score 0):

From [the PHP Docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php).

> [There] is a header that starts with the string "HTTP/" (case is not significant), which will be used to figure out the HTTP status code to send. For example, **if you have configured Apache to use a PHP script to handle requests for missing files** (using the ErrorDocument directive), you may want to make sure that your script generates the proper status code.

```
<?php
  header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
?>
```

Emphasis added.

So, wherever you have 'exited' your code when accessed from a browser, use the header string above.

Comment: but how can I show the content of the not found page (not_found.php)? At the top of the AJAX page, I check the source of access, if it is from the browser address bar, then I exit the code, I use $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']. Would appreciate if you show me a complete example . Thank you.

Comment: Post some of your code, please. I'll try and plug things into the correct spot.

Comment: Please look at the original post, I have updated it with a code and description. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks. My original answer still applies actually.. Right above the `exit;`, just place the `header` and that should work. Make sure that you don't actually output any HTML before that `header` gets called, else you'll get a PHP error.

Comment: Thanks @WillemLabu, but how can I view the content of the page "not_found.php"? I don't see any connection with that page from your code. Also, I have tried it out but I get empty white page :( Any configuration to be done at Apache to make this happen? Thank you very much

Comment: Thanks @WillemLabu, I have solved the problem and I have posted the full answer, my issue was how to show the not_found.php page! And the file_get_contents was the solution :)